# Hide Wordpress nav menu item with ACF true/false field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a pretty standard menu in Wordpress that is my primary nav. I used ACF to add a true/false field for each menus item. So the user can select yes to show the item or no to hide the item. My default, they're all set to yes. Heres a screenshot:

[image]

However, I'm becoming stuck when it comes to the function I need to add to make it all work properly. I tried a few different things, but here's one example:

I added this as a function via a simple plugin (I don't have access to a child theme functions.php file...

```
function hide_menu_items($items, $menu, $args) {
    foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
        $show_in_menu = get_field('show_in_menu', $item);
        if (!$show_in_menu) {
            $items[$key]->classes[] = 'hide-menu-item';
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'hide_menu_items', 10, 3);
```

Along with the CSS:

```
.div-c08242d .hide-menu-item {
    display: none;
}
```

But I can't seem to get it to work. Ive been using a block editor page builder thing called cwicly, and I thought perhaps its displaying the menu differently to how Wordpress usually works... The menu structure is as follows:

```
<div id="div-c7e67e7" class="div-c08242d">
    <nav id="menu-cb0dd9c" class="menu-cface62" aria-label="Main Menu">
        <ul class="cc-menu hor" aria-label="Main Menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="cc-menu-main" tabindex="-1">Button 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="cc-menu-main" tabindex="-1">Button 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="cc-menu-main" tabindex="-1">Button 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="cc-menu-main" tabindex="-1">Button 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="cc-menu-main" tabindex="-1">Button 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

So, I'm not sure if the toggle switch is even applying anything to the `<li>` items and if it was, I would assume Id be able to achieve this with CSS only?

Perhaps I'm also looking at this the wrong way, so any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu_items/

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'show_in_menu', 10, 2);
function show_in_menu($items, $args)
{
  // $items = the nav items' HTML
  // $args = details about the nav items
}
```

You could remove the string based on the show_in_menu condition, or target the menu item by id. I didn't flush out the solution because the link above has several starter code snippets that will probably put you on the right track!

Comment: Thanks for the direction :) Im still struggling a little bit - Should I be seeing the ACF toggle switch apply a true or false in the front end inspector? I assumes it would add this onto one of the li items so I could then target it?